# Candy-crush-like game logic

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am doing a candy-crush-like game, but I have a problem creating the logic.
Let's take an example of this map:

### 1, 3, 2, 1

### 2, 2, 2, 3

### 1, 3, 2, 2,

### 3, 3, 3, 2

How would I check if, in one of those rows, there are repeating numbers in row, greater than or equal to 3 times?

I tried doing "if statements" for each case, but I dont't think that's a very good idea, for each case, there should be special function for that... or at least create one.

Solutin can be in PHP or Javascript.

Comment: I suppose that depends on how you are storing the information? In Javascript, in PHP and what does jQuery have to do with it?

Comment: Without knowing how you are displaying/storing your matrix (and what language you're doing it in) there isn't much we can help here

Comment: I may store it in an array in php example: $list[x][y] = 2

Comment: Ok, well when you have decided, have tried something and have a problem you can let us know.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using a string representation like below then preg_match() may be helpful.

```
$rows = array(
  '1321',
  '2223',
  '1322',
  '3332',
  '3222',
  '12312322222222123123'
);


foreach($rows as $row) {
  echo $row .' 3+ repeating values: ';
  if(preg_match('/(1{3,}|2{3,}|3{3,})/',$row,$matches)) {
    echo 'Yes';
    echo ', found at pos. ' . strpos($row, $matches[0]);
    echo ' (' . $matches[0] . ')';
  } else {
    echo 'No';
  }

  echo "\n";
};
```

Output is:

```
1321 3+ repeating values: No
2223 3+ repeating values: Yes, found at pos. 0 (222)
1322 3+ repeating values: No
3332 3+ repeating values: Yes, found at pos. 0 (333)
3222 3+ repeating values: Yes, found at pos. 1 (222)
12312322222222123123 3+ repeating values: Yes, found at pos. 6 (22222222)
```

You can play around with the code at http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c183683c96af513e9a4b539ed8f713a685f34541

Alternative version using PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE flag, as suggested by @Mark Baker

```
foreach($rows as $row) {
  echo $row .' 3 repeating values: ';
  if(preg_match('/(1{3,}|2{3,}|3{3,})/',$row,$matches,PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)) {
    list($match, $pos) = $matches[0];
    echo "Yes, found at pos. $pos ($match)\n";
  } else {
    echo "No\n";
  }
};
```

Comment: After i get the result, that in line 2 there are 3 repeating values, how can i get their position? :)

Comment: Perhaps by using the `PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE` flag with `preg_match()` [Demo](https://3v4l.org/qRspl)

Comment: Updated my answer. The key is to look at $matches which is an array of matching patterns and search for it in $row. this should give you an idea on how to use preg_match() for your benefit.

Comment: wow thank you a lot, it is perfect for me.

Comment: How can i get how many repeating values are there, or the end of repeated values to remove them?

Comment: In case of a match look at $matches[0]. Code example adjusted. If this answers your question then please mark as valid soution and award points for it.

Answer (score 2):

I have an idea of doing the same task.
You have 4 rows and in each row you have 4 columns, you create simple array like that

```
$rows = array(
  '1321',
  '2223',
  '1322',
  '3332'
);
```

and start the loop for printing elements.
You create a random number in the range from (1 to 4) (it is for row selector which means in which row combination of 3 same number are exists), after this you have start a loop and generate random number in all other rows except the selected combination row, in loop generate number then compare it if it is same then print it in that row if not then loop is executed again.